# How to fit histogram with bimodal with Python?

Tags: python, gaussian

[image]

I have those data with Gaussian distributions (histogram), how should I fit it using gaussian model? The sklearn mixture.GMM isn't be used because the input data is not histogram.

Comment: Is it really a **biomodal** distribution or a **bimodal** distribution ?

Comment: i am sorry ,it is a bimodal

Comment: What is the format of your data **"Gaussian distributions (histogram)"** or **"input data is not histogram"** ?